# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for vectors, proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The proof I have written for the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for vectors is below:

1. I would be grateful if anyone could spot and errors or inefficiencies?
2. Can this proof be easily adapted to cover complex numbers also?

Many thanks for your help.

Theorem
$||u||\space ||v|| \geq |\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|$, where $u,v∈V=\Bbb R^n$.

Proof
If $v=0$, $|\left \langle u,0 \right \rangle|=||u||\space ||0||$, therefore $0=0$, similarly for $u=0$.

For $u,v \neq 0$, we need a vector orthogonal to $u_v$ then we can use the Pythagorean Theorem to prove. The standard formula to make $z$ a projection of $u$, orthogonal to $v$ is $z=u-\frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}v$.

As $v$ and $z$ are orthogonal we can apply the Pythagorean Theorem, as the length of the hypotenuse $u$ is greater than the length of $u_v$:

$||u||^2 = ||u - \frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}v||^2 + ||\frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle}v||^2 \geq ||\frac{\left \langle u,v \right \rangle}{\left \langle v,v \right \rangle} v||^2 = \frac{|\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|^2} {(||v||^2)^2}||v||^2 = \frac{|\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|^2} {||v||^2}$.

$\implies ||u||^2 \geq \frac{|\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|^2} {||v||^2}$

$\implies ||u||^2 ||v||^2 \geq |\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|^2$

$\implies ||u|| \space ||v|| \geq |\left \langle u,v \right \rangle|$

Q.E.D.

Comment: The projection should be $z=u-\frac{\langle u,v\rangle}{\langle v,v\rangle}v$ without the modulus signs. It is applicable to complex numbers as well.

Comment: Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

The only subtlety in the complex case is whether to define $z$ as $u-\frac{\langle u,\,v\rangle}{\langle v,\,v\rangle}v$ or $u-\frac{\langle v,\,u\rangle}{\langle v,\,v\rangle}v$; either would work in the real case, but$$\Vert u-zv\Vert^2=\Vert u\Vert^2+|z|^2\Vert v\Vert^2=2\Re\Vert u,\,zv\Vert^2$$implies $z$ needs to be $\tfrac{\langle u,\,v\rangle}{\langle v,\,v\rangle}$ ($\tfrac{\langle v,\,u\rangle}{\langle v,\,v\rangle}$) if the inner product is linear (antilinear) in the rightmost argument, which is convention of physicists (mathematicians).